# Python: cannot get rid of TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

Input

```
[['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'],['6','7','8'],['e','f','g']]
```

Output should be:

```
1, 2, 3
a, b, c
6, 7, 8
e, f, g
```

Code:

```
def print_row(los):
    print ', '.join(los)


def print_table(los):
    lose = []
    if los  == []:
        return
    else:
        return print_row(los[0]) + print_table(los[1:])
```

Currently:

```
print_table([['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'],['6','7','8'],['e','f','g']])
```

Gives:

```
1, 2, 3
a, b, c
6, 7, 8
e, f, g

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect adding the two functions will do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function returns `None` (an empty `return` statement). Return an empty string instead:

```
if los == []:
    return ''
```

You also have a `lose` definition there that is never used, and you can test for the empty list with `not los`. Last but not least, since `return` exits the function early, the `else:` statement is optional.

Next, `print_row()` returns `None` as well, since you don't return *anything* from it. Simply discard it's return value:

```
def print_table(los):
    if not los:
        return ''
    print_row(los[0])
    return print_table(los[1:])
```

Note that you never use the return value of `print_table` anyway, so you may as well not return anything; simply test if there is anything *to* print:

```
def print_table(los):
    if los:
        print_row(los[0])
        print_table(los[1:])
```

Now you can just inline the `print_row` function (which is just a one-liner):

```
def print_table(los):
    if los:
        print ', '.join(los[0])
        print_table(los[1:])
```

This is still recursive; Python isn't that strong at recursion, but it *can* do looping very well:

```
def print_table(los):
    for sublist in los:
        print ', '.join(sublist)
```

which can be reduced to a join on newlines too:

```
def print_table(los):
    print '\n'.join(', '.join(sublist) for sublist in los)
```

Comment: This won't completely solve it, `print_row()` also returns `None`.

Comment: still returns TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Answer (score 3):

The other answer explains why what you have doesn't work, but here's an easier way to do it:

```
l = [['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'],['6','7','8'],['e','f','g']]

print '\n'.join(', '.join(j) for j in l)
```

```
1, 2, 3
a, b, c
6, 7, 8
e, f, g
```

---

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`str.join(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)